# Calculating average of list from certain point in list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, math

I have a question, I know that it is possible to calculate the average of a list but is it possible to calculate average but from a certain point?

For example:

```
def Average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

list = [2, 8, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1]
average = Average(lst)
```

Printing average of the list:

```
print("Average of the list =", round(average, 2))
```

Output: 
    Average of the list = 4.14

Say we want to keep the first 3 values and average the rest to have only 4 values in the list

So my new list is:

```
list = [2, 8, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1] 
new_list = [2, 8, 6, 12.25]
```

**Edit 1**

Thank you all for your answers. I have another question, say, I don't know the length of my list and I just want 4 elements in my new list. How could I tackle this?

Comment: Where is 12.25 coming from?

Comment: as far as i understand 12.25 is the avg of all the other elements (altough its not correct) in the list after the 3rd element.

Comment: Meaning the OP wants to calculate  the avg only from some of the elements of the initial list and append this to a new list consisting of elements that were not used for the avg calculation + the calculatio nresult

Comment: @Momo how the 12.25 is the average of all elements after the third element?

Comment: @marxmacher thanks for your comment, I have another question. Say, I don't know the length of my list and I just want 4 elements in my new list. How could I tackle this?

Comment: @MehaParekh yeah, its the average after third element

Comment: @Momo 12.25 is not the correct one. Please edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to round off the list from an index (Here 3)

```
mylist = [2, 8, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1]

def round_list(lst, index):
    avg = [sum(lst[int(index):])/(len(lst)-index)]
    new_lst = (lst[:int(index)]) + avg
    return new_lst

new_list = round_list(mylist, 3)
print(new_list)
```

output : [2, 8, 6, 3.25]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
l=[2, 8, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1]
pt=3
l=l[:pt]+[sum(l[pt:])/len(l[pt:])]
```

output:

```
[2, 8, 6, 3.25]
```

Comment: Your 12.25 as the average of remaining elements is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another question, say, I don't know the length of my list and I just want 4 elements in my new list. How could I tackle this?

Comment: Can you rephrase?

Comment: @Ahmed Farhan Say that next list has 10 elements and I want to again have a new list with 4 elements

Answer (score 0):

Your function `Average` will work just as well on a `slice` of the original list.

So, for your example:

```
new_list = list[:3] + [Average(list[3:])]
print(new_list)
```

Will output:

[2, 8, 6, 3.25]

The `slice` syntax used here is useful fro selecting only sub sequences of a list. In summary, the syntax is `list[start:stop:step]` with each of `start`, `stop` and `step` being optional. You can read more [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html). The examples given will be particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to calculate a list elements average for a specific region from the list and create a new list with the rest of elements and the specific region average you can use:

```
import statistics

l = [2, 8, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1] 

start = 3
end = 5

new_list = [*l[:start], statistics.mean(l[start: end]), *l[end:]]
new_list
```

**output:**

```
[2, 8, 6, 5, 2, 1]
```